# Alternative to using goto statement in C#

Tags: c#

I am new to the C# language. I just started learning a few weeks ago and am trying to create a simple application using the Visual Studio console. I want to have all the options on a main menu where you can go to any other menu. But I also want to be able to return to the main menu from anywhere in the application.

The only way in my (limited) experience it can see to do this is with goto statements. I know that a lot of programmers consider goto statements to be evil! In a modern language like C#, is there an alternative way of doing it?

Comment: It would be helpful to show code of what you're using now.

Comment: Show how you're doing it now and I'm sure you'll get plenty of alternatives.

Comment: Usually using a goto is considered a code smell, and the only time it is potentially of use, is to break out of deeply nested loops. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: I think this will probably become more of an opinion question... There are so many ways to not use a goto and it really will come down to application design.

Comment: `Goto` is used for flow control. Depending on what your code is trying to accomplish, there are many different flow control strategies. My definite go to (pardon the pun) strategies of flow control are `foreach` and `if` statements, however both have two completely different uses. For more information on flow control look at MSDN's article on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147286(v=vs.88).aspx

Comment: Do not use `GOTO` statements this is not COBOL or some other antiquated language it's C# .NET do some reading / research

Comment: This question is too generic and does not address a real _programming issue_. You might have better chance to get some pointers on http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Holy moley... I think OP get's that question needs improvement... Can probably stop downvoting him now (not that it matters one way or another as has 1 rep)

Comment: I haven't started coding it yet. I didn't want to start by using goto statements than have to change large chunks of code after.

Comment: the question is not to generic.. I think that the wording is off.. however LeeWay you want to read up on Events particularly Click Events

Comment: I agree with  [alykins'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537470/alternative-to-using-goto-statement-in-c-sharp#comment41700861_26537470) comment. This is not a bad question. Just a beginner's one. And those are (supposed to be) acceptable here on SO.

Comment: are you trying to create a Dos Style of program.. why not start off with trying to do this as a WinForms App..

Comment: I think in 3rd gen languages like C, C++, VB, C# it is logically impossible to design an algorithm (write code) that MUST use a Goto statement. In other words, you can always restructure the code to do without Goto statements and satisfy any algorithm.  For that fact alone, they should never be used in these types of languages (except for desperate hacks...)  COBOL may be the exception but I don't think so.  (VB6 error handling aside...Not many options there)

Comment: I think the best thing for you to do is not worry about it until it comes up. If you find yourself being "forced" to use it, then post that question with that code and something explaining what you are trying to do. When you have that, if you don't inherently see the answer, we will be able to point you right.

Comment: `Delphi` is a powerful language as well, it can utilize the `goto` command but I personally would never us it in my delphi code

Answer (score 2):

Instead of Goto, which is commonly referred to as evil (lol), you can make a function called

`ShowMainMenu`

and then call that function whenever you want to show the Main Menu.  Gotos are not implicitly evil, just bad practice.  If you are an expert, and decided a quick hack is best using a Goto - you wouldn't lose your job :).  But for beginners, you should restructure the code entirely to avoid them.

Comment: If you were to use `GOTO` here where I work I know for a fact that my boss would fire you on the spot.. `Gotos are just bad  practice`

Comment: Except if the alternative was a months work plus testing plus QA plus UAT....  Sometimes a little little goto in legacy code is all you need.  But I agree - I would fire myself lol

Comment: I think the only time it has use that I can think of is within a switch statement after an evaluation to jump to a different case (for example `case 1: if(someMethod())? return true: goto default;` ) but that is one of the few places I can think of.

Comment: Well there is always the VB6 error handling - no options except `ON ERROR GOTO label`

Comment: I was omitting that horrible language as it makes me cry inside xD

Comment: i think it makes all coders cry....:)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what technology your using, or code.  In theory your example would be:

```
public static class Menu
{
     public static LaunchPage(string page)
     {
          switch(value) {
              case "About":
                   // Show new form, page, something.
                   break;

              default:
                  // Go home by default.
                  break;
          }
     }
}
```

The theory is simple, in your code you call: `Menu.LaunchPage("About");` and it will trigger your `switch` which will execute the code to go to that page or form.  Vice versa, so you could read particular events for navigation.

A simple example, it is also a bit rough around the edges but hopefully it gets you started. Without more information we can't help.

**Update:**
To help clarify even further, you may not even need the above.  You could in theory have a button, that when clicked simply goes to the desired page:

```
protected void btnAbout(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     // Go to About
}
```

Another way, without more information the question remains far too broad.