# Alternative to goto statement

Tags: c#, goto

I'm pretty new to C# (started learning it a week ago) with a little bit of experience in batch and Expression 2, and I've been working on a text-based game in an attempt to learn more. I used goto statements at first, but according to pretty much everyone I've found, goto statements are some amalgam of death and despair, so I want to learn cleaner, less evil ways to achieve the same effect. Here's a crummy example script I made to demonstrate what I mean:

```
using System;

namespace TestScript
{
class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       string ConsoleReadinator;
        string ConsoleReadinator2;
        int Go = 0;

    mainmenu:
        do
        {
            Go = 0;
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Main Menu:");
            Console.WriteLine("Store or something");
            ConsoleReadinator = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            if (ConsoleReadinator == "STORE") { Go = 1; }
        } while (Go == 0);

      // In-game store example

        {
            Go = 0;
            do
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("In-game store I guess");
                Console.WriteLine("Stuff you can buy, etc");
                ConsoleReadinator2 = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
                if (ConsoleReadinator2 == "GO") { Go = 1; }
            } while (Go == 0);
            goto mainmenu;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This script is functional, but I'd like to avoid using `goto` as a way to go back to previous statements in order to navigate menus and maybe to repeat algorithms for turn-based games. I read about using methods for this in [Alternative to using goto statement in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26537470/alternative-to-using-goto-statement-in-c-sharp) (which is basically the same question I have, except a bit more vague), but the example Greg made there didn't work for me at all, to the point that it's probably not worth trying to make that particular example work.

Comment: I think a more appropriate site for this question to be a site http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Yeah, don't use goto statements, ever

Comment: @Liam The whole point of the post was to not use goto statements, ever.

Comment: I'll probably get rousted, but after about 20 years of development - DOS, Windows, C++, ASP, C#, etc. I decided that a goto inside of a method was a great way to simply handle errors in complex code. My opposite number, C++ Senior Engineer and scary smart, agrees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use recursion in order to go back and execute code again. For this purpose you could move your code to a separate method and call it in this method:

```
class Program
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
        string ConsoleReadinator;
        string ConsoleReadinator2;
        Method(0);
   }
 
   private static void Method(int Go)
   {    
        do
        {
            ..
        } while (Go == 0);

      // In-game store example

        do
        {
           ...
        } while (Go == 0);
        Method(Go);
   }
}
```

Or you could use loops in a better way. Let's have a look at the example when we want user to enter an integer number :

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int num;

       // This loop ends only when user enters proper integer number
       do
       {
          Console.Clear();
          Console.Write("Please enter some integer number: ");
       } while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num));                      
   }
```

This could be done other way with recursion:

```
   public static int EnterNumber()
   {
       Console.Clear();
       Console.Write("Please enter some integer number: ");

       // if the number is successfully parsed return number else run this method again
       return int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out num) ? num : EnterNumber();
   }

   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       int num = EnterNumber();
   }
```

With all the options we have (methods, loops and recursion) there is no practical use case for using `GO TO`s anymore.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can see you want an *infinite loop*:

```
  ...
  while (true) 
  {
      do
      {
         ...
      } while (Go == 0);

      Go = 0;

      do
      {
         ...
      } while (Go == 0);
  }
```

Comment: I commented on this a few minutes ago saying that it worked, and it does for this example, but I neglected to mention that there's going to be multiple options; not just a store. If I used an infinite loop like this, I think I would have to cycle through every menu, unless maybe I used a lot of loops.

Comment: @Rowan Tarshis: why not adding yet another menu item, *Exit* on which just call `break;` (to leave just the infinite loop above) or `return;` (to leave the `Main` function and thus the program)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. By "another menu item," do you mean another menu, like the store, or something else? Furthermore, by "Exit on which just call `break;` (to leave just the infinite loop above)," do you mean that it would `break;` into a second infinite loop, or am I misunderstanding that?

Comment: @Rowan Tarshis: yes, like `"Store"`, so when user print, say, "Exit" we just leave the loop

Answer (score 0):

In general you use methods or lambda expressions. So your mainmenu would become a method that you call again at the end of the code.

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion would be to use a switch case construct like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string ConsoleReadinator;
    string MENU_TEXT = "Main Menu:";
    string ADDITIONAL_INFO = "Store or something";

    bool endProg = false;


    ConsoleReadinator = printMenu(MENU_TEXT, ADDITIONAL_INFO);

    // as long "EXIT" is not typed
    while (!endProg)
    {

        switch (ConsoleReadinator)
        {
            case "STORE":
                // Do your Store Stuff
                // maybe change MENU_TEXT and ADDITIONAL_INFO 
                // and print a new Menu
                ConsoleReadinator = printMenu(MENU_TEXT, ADDITIONAL_INFO);
                break;
            case "GO":
                // Do your Go Stuff
                break;
            case "EXIT":
                endProg = true;   // set exit condition to true
                break;

            default:                        
                break;
        }
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}

// one Method to use for Menu display
public static string printMenu(string menuText, string additionalInfo)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine(menuText);
    Console.WriteLine(additionalInfo);

    return Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();

}
```